# Swift await for async request to complete

Tags: swift, core-motion

I have the following function by which I want to return a Int

```
  private func queryPedometerSteps(currentStartDate: Date, currentLastDate: Date) -> Int {
    var stepsGiven = 0
    pedometer.queryPedometerData(from: currentStartDate, to: currentLastDate){data, error in
      guard let pedometerData = data else { return }
      let steps = pedometerData.numberOfSteps.intValue
      print("entered query from \(currentStartDate) to \(currentLastDate) and stepped \(steps)")
      stepsGiven = steps
    }
    return stepsGiven
  }
```

I am using this function to return the steps, by which is assigned to a variable and then use it for another function, like this

```
let numberOfStepsBetweenDates = queryPedometerSteps(currentStartDate: currentStartDate, currentLastDate: currentLastDate)
anotherCall(numberOfStepsBetweenDates: Int)
```

I want the pedometer.queryPedometerData to finish before returning the stepsGiven. The code as it is, the function always returns 0. I already tried Dispatch groups, and semaphores, but for some reason the code stops working when I use these. Does somebody have any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you really need to be synchrone? Or do you want to trigger something when you get the value? Because that's different. Making  asynchrone into synchrone is usually a bad idea and reveals a misunderstanding on how this works. What's the code that calls `queryPedometerSteps(currentStartDate:currentLastDate:)`?

Comment: Change the function so that it takes a completion handler, and pass `stepsGiven` via that handler. As written, this cannot work.

Comment: @Larme sorry maybe I did not make myself very clear. queryPedometerSteps is an async call from the package CMPedometer. I already added the code that calls this function

Comment: @Gereon ok Im gonna try it, thanks !

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function like so:

```
private func queryPedometerSteps(currentStartDate: Date, 
                                 currentLastDate: Date,
                                 completion: (Int?) -> Void) {
  pedometer.queryPedometerData(from: currentStartDate, to: currentLastDate) { data, error in
    guard let pedometerData = data else { return completion(nil) }
    let steps = pedometerData.numberOfSteps.intValue
    print("entered query from \(currentStartDate) to \(currentLastDate) and stepped \(steps)")
    completion(steps)
  }
}
```

your calling code will then look like this:

```
queryPedometerSteps(currentStartDate: currentStartDate, currentLastDate: currentLastDate) { steps in 
  guard let steps = steps else { return }
  anotherCall(numberOfStepsBetweenDates: steps)
}
```

(you may have to mark the closures as `@escaping` - I haven't checked the Pedometer API)

Comment: it worked, thank you so much! Im new to swift and there are still many things I dont understand. I guess Im gonna read the whole documentation :D